# Can anyone identify this type of connector

Tags: pcb, components, connector, video, video-transmitter

I have a Lawmate 2.4 Ghz Video transmitter which has a small 4 pin input plug. I want to find out what the proper name for this type of connector so I can buy spares for it - maybe someone here can identify it for me.  I've attached a picture below:

[image]

Comment: You can search for "Molex" connectors. You will need to measure the contact spacing, contact size, etc.

Comment: molex connectors seem to be a bit larger than this, this thing is only about 6mm across.

Comment: @mdresser: Molex makes lots and lots of connectors, some large and some very small.  You can't say from size alone whether it was made by Molex.

Comment: I've looked up Lawmate's line. Sellers do bill the connector as Molex. Perhaps you can tell us the model number and look for replacement parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This connector is like JST connector,the MODEL NO is SHR-04V-S-B.Right now our company don't have this 4 pin connector.